# Sum of the fifth powers of the first n numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove that $1^5+2^5+\dots+n^5= \dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2(2n^2+2n-1)}{12}$

I  think we use induction to solve this problem.

**Base case**: When $n = 1$, we have $1^5 = 1$. The formula gives $1$, which is correct.

**Inductive hypothesis**: Assume that the formula holds for some value of $k,$ where $k$ is a positive integer.

**Inductive step:** We want to show that the formula also holds for $k+1$.
From here I can't make progress so please help me.

Comment: Those parenthesis are not balanced.

Comment: You have to add $(n+1)^5$ to the right-hand side and show that the result is equal to $(n+1)^2(n+2)^2(2(n+1)^2+2(n+1)+1)/12$.

Comment: Or "add $(k+1)^5$", to fit OP's notation for the inductive step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to show that
$$1^5+2^5+\dots+k^5 +(k+1)^5 = \dfrac{(k+1)^2 (k+2)^2(2(k+1)^2+2(k+1)-1)}{12}.$$
By the inductive hypothesis, we have:
$$1^5+2^5+\dots+k^5= \dfrac{k^2(k+1)^2(2k^2+2k+1)}{12}.$$
Now add $(k+1)^5$:
\begin{align}
1^5+2^5+\dots+k^5 +(k+1)^5 &= \dfrac{k^2(k+1)^2(2k^2+2k-1)}{12} + (k+1)^5\\
&= \dfrac{k^2(k+1)^2(2k^2+2k-1)}{12} + \dfrac{12(k+1)^5}{12}\\
&= \dfrac{(k+1)^2 (k^2(2k^2+2k-1) + 12(k+1)^3)}{12}\\
&= \dfrac{(k+1)^2 (2k^4+2k^3-k^2 + 12k^3+36k^2+36k+12)}{12}\\
&= \dfrac{(k+1)^2 (\color{red}{2k^4+14k^3+35k^2+36k+12})}{12}.
\end{align}
Notice that:
\begin{align}
(k+2)^2(2(k+1)^2+2(k+1)-1)&=(k^2+4k+4)(2k^2+4k+2+2k+1)\\
&=\color{red}{2 k^4 + 14 k^3 + 35 k^2 + 36 k + 12}.
\end{align}
Therefore
$$1^5+2^5+\dots+k^5 +(k+1)^5 = \dfrac{(k+1)^2 (k+2)^2(2(k+1)^2+2(k+1)-1)}{12}.$$
As we wanted to show.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you forget $(k+2)^2$ in what we want to show?

Comment: Thanks, and yes I did. I will fix it right away.